# Circular dependency in utility functions

Tags: javascript, eslint

#### Some Background

I've been developing an [ESLint plugin](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor) to catch Protractor/Jasmine specific code style violations.

In Protractor, there are two important notations: [`ElementFinder`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder) and [`ElementArrayFinder`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder).

- `ElementFinder` is a special object that corresponds to a single element

  - is typically defined via `element(by.smth(""))` or `$("css selector")`.
- `ElementArrayFinder` is a special object that corresponds to an array of elements

  - is typically defined via `element.all(by.smth(""))` or `$$("css selector")`

And, all of these notations can be chained. `ElementFinder` can also be retrieved from an `ElementArrayFinder` via `get()`, `first()` or `last()` methods, e.g.:

```
element.all(by.className("someClass")).element(by.tagName("td"));
```

#### The Task

In multiple ESLint rules I've been developing so far, I needed to **locate the ESLint *Call Expressions* that are either `ElementFinder` or `ElementArrayFinder`.**

Currently, I've come up with two utility functions that are circularly dependent on each other:

[`is-element-finder.js`](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/blob/master/lib/is-element-finder.js):

```
'use strict'

/**
 * Checks if a given node is an ElementFinder instance.
 *
 * @fileoverview Utility function to determine if a node is an ElementFinder
 * @author Alexander Afanasyev
 */

var elementArrayFinderGetMethods = [
  'get',
  'last',
  'first'
]
var elementFinderConstructors = [
  '$',
  'element'
]

module.exports = function (node) {
  var callee = node.callee
  if (!callee) {
    return false
  }

  // handling raw $ and element
  if (elementFinderConstructors.indexOf(callee.name) > -1) {
    return true
  }

  // handling $ and element chaining
  if (callee.type === 'MemberExpression' && callee.property) {
    if (elementFinderConstructors.indexOf(callee.property.name) > -1) {
      return true
    }

    // got element finder from element array finder
    var isElementArrayFinderMethod = elementArrayFinderGetMethods.indexOf(callee.property.name) > -1
    if (isElementArrayFinderMethod && callee.object && isElementArrayFinder(callee.object)) {
      return true
    }
  }

  return false
}
var isElementArrayFinder = require('./is-element-array-finder')
```

[`is-element-array-finder.js`](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/blob/master/lib/is-element-array-finder.js):

```
'use strict'

/**
 * Checks a given CallExpression node is an ElementArrayFinder instance.
 *
 * @fileoverview Utility function to determine if a node is an ElementArrayFinder
 * @author Alexander Afanasyev
 */

module.exports = function isElementArrayFinder (node) {
  var callee = node.callee

  if (callee) {
    // handling $$ shortcut
    if (callee.name === '$$') {
      return true
    }

    // handling element.all() and nested .all()
    if (callee.property && (callee.property.name === 'all' || callee.property.name === '$$')) {
      if (callee.object) {
        if (callee.object.type === 'Identifier') {
          return callee.object.name === 'element'
        }

        if (callee.object.type === 'CallExpression') {
          return isElementFinder(callee.object) || isElementArrayFinder(callee.object)
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return false
}
var isElementFinder = require('./is-element-finder')
```

The argument `node` here is a `CallExpression` ESLint object.

#### The Problem

These two functions successfully pass all of my tests and locate `ElementFinder` and `ElementArrayFinder` instances.

But, because they both can be chained, each of the functions need to call another, which leads to a circular dependency. How would you approach removing the circular dependency? I would also appreciate any comments about the code style and readability.

Note: using [Standard JS style](https://standardjs.com/).

<sup>I understand that there is a bit of a context in order to understand the problem, but I am open to elaborate more or add any additional information.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Circular dependency

Although I find this circular dependency fishy, I don't know how to remove it. Maybe it's not possible.

However, as long as the circular dependency exists,
it would be better if the two functions were defined in the same file.
I don't like having them in separate files because:

1. It can be misleading, suggesting that one file is usable without the other, but it's not
2. The `elementArrayFinderGetMethods` and the conditions on it in `is-element-finder` violates the encapsulation of `isElementArrayFinder`

#### Readability

Symmetry helps readability.
In `isElementFinder` you use early return on `callee`,
but not in `isElementArrayFinder`.

You could further reduce the nesting by lifting a `callee.object` condition to one level higher:

```
  if (callee.object && callee.property && (callee.property.name === 'all' || callee.property.name === '$$')) {
    if (callee.object.type === 'Identifier') {
      return callee.object.name === 'element'
    }

    if (callee.object.type === 'CallExpression') {
      return isElementFinder(callee.object) || isElementArrayFinder(callee.object)
    }
  }
```

The `callee.property && (callee.property.name === 'all' || callee.property.name === '$$')` condition could be a good candidate to extract to a helper method.